# How to customize wtforms' FileField as an image button?

Tags: html, css, wtforms

I'm trying to load an image from a project's folder to use as icon instead of the normal "choose file". Here's what I've tried so far. Not only the image isn't loaded, the old button is only displayed in half.

HTML

```
<div>{{ form.tweet_image(class="submit-image-tweet")}}</div>
```

CSS

```
.submit-image-tweet {
    background: url(../templates/images/camera_icon.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to wrap your file `input` into a `label` and style that instead.

The cross-browser spec on styling native elements is improving. However, if you need bullet-proof support, this is still the best way.

```css
.file{
  display:block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/device-camera-icon.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.file input{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label class="file">
  <input type="file"/>
</label>
```

Comment: is there a way to store the icon image inside the project's folder and call it with background: url instead of using the image link from the web?

Comment: Yeah, just replace it with you own url. I used something random because I obviously don't have access to your files and environment.

Comment: Whenever I try to replace the url with image path (../templates/images/file_name.png) the button dissapears

Comment: Then your path is wrong. I don't know your folder structure.

Comment: I check again. The folder path isn't wrong. Even as I type, the IDE suggests the path for me. Maybe the url only works if it is web link and not folder path?

Comment: That is impossible. If you want, get rid of background-size: cover; Maybe your image is reacting weird to that setting.