# Changing text used in Flask form file upload fields

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm using a Flask form with a file field together with boostrap and wtforms. How I can I change the text on the button ("Choose file") and the text "no file chosen"?

Comment: I don't think you can, they are generated by the browser.

Comment: Even I had similar requirement and the solution can be found in the answer by @Serg Chernata. it worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41935979/6853137